# JMeter populate nested json request body using CSV DataSet

Tags: java, json, csv, jmeter

I'm generating http requests in JMeter using CSV dataset.
I'd like to generate nested json like the following one:

```
{
  "name": "some_name",
  "from": {
    "lat": 20.1,
    "lng": 32.5
  }
  "to": {
    "lat": 41.2,
    "lng": 54.8
  }
}
```

I parametrized http sampler request body looks as follows in JMeter:

```
{
  "name": "${name}",
  "from": {
    "lat": ${from_lat},
    "lng": ${from_lng}
  }
  "to": {
    "lat": ${to_lat},
    "lng": ${to_lng}
  }
}
```

Test data set is as follows:

```
name,from_lat,from_lng,to_lat,to_lng
some_name,20.1,32.5,41.2,54.8
```

Instead of required json JMeter compose the following:

```
{
  "name": "some_name",
  "from": {
    "lat": ${from_lat},
    "lng": ${from_lng}
  }
  "to": {
    "lat": ${to_lat},
    "lng": ${to_lng}
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to make JMeter substitute the `from_lat,from_lng,to_lat,to_lng` parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set ignore first line only set to true , as you are adding column names in the dataset,
here is my CSV config file settings
[image]

and the result 
[image]

[image: r]

You can refer this  [blog](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/01/load-test-with-unique-users/)

For more info on CSV config  [Follow this link](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

Comment: I actually forgot to add these values to the variable names field in configuration, such a silly mistake :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your test plan
2. **Provide full path to your CSV file** (or relative to current JMeter working directory)

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

   No extra configuration should be required.
3. Your HTTP Request body looks just fine
4. Verify that JMeter substitutes variables with actual values from CSV using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

   [image: JMeter verify CSV Data]

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

If something goes wrong check out *jmeter.log* file, normally it should contain enough information to get to the bottom of the issue